# Getting half the frequency and double the duration from a sine wave generated using C and played using aplay

Tags: audio, c

I am trying to generate a sine wave of 440Hz frequency that lasts for 10 seconds using the following C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double sine(double amp, double freq, double time);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sample_rate = 48000;
    double freq = 440;
    double amp = 1;
    double duration = 10;
    double time = 0;
    double val = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int i = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen("sine.bin", "wb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    while (i <= sample_rate * duration)
    {
        val = 32767.0 * sine(amp, freq, time);
        temp = (int) val;
        fwrite((const void*) &temp, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        time = i / (1.0 * sample_rate);
        i++;
    }
}

double sine(double amp, double freq, double time)
{
    return amp * sin(2.0 * M_PI * freq * time);
}
```

However, I am getting a sine wave of 220Hz that lasts for 20 seconds instead. How can I modify this code to produce a sine wave of 440Hz that lasts for 10 seconds? I have compiled and run this code using:

```
gcc sound.c  -Wall -Wextra -lm -o sound && ./sound
aplay -r 48000 -f S16_LE sine.bin
```

Comment: Are you `fclose()`ing your file?

Comment: Also, do you know how many bits are in your `int`?  It might be that `int` is 32-bits but you're telling your `aplay` utility that they are 16-bit iintegers.

Comment: No, I'm not closing my file, thanks for pointing that mistake out, as it turns out I was mistaken about the number of bits and changing the int for a short fixes it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to generate a 16 bit sound file, using int`means it is 32 or 64 bit, so`short` must be used when working with a 16 bit audio

[C Programming/limits.h](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/limits.h)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double sine(double amp, double freq, double time);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sample_rate = 48000;
    double freq = 220;
    double amp = 1;
    double duration = 10;
    double time = 0;
    double val = 0;
    short temp = 0;
    int i = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen("sine.bin", "wb");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    while (i <= sample_rate*duration)
    {
        val = 32767.0*sine(amp, freq, time);
        temp = (short) val;
        fwrite((const void*) &temp,sizeof(short),1,fp);
        time = i/(1.0*sample_rate);
        i++;
    }
}
double sine(double amp, double freq, double time)
{
        return amp*sin(2.0*M_PI*freq*time);
}
```

Comment: You should `fclose()` the file.  And you should be more careful and explicit in mixing floating-point and integer types together,